# FailedPreconditionError: /home/timucin/Thesis/Tagger-master8/train; Is a directory

Tags: python, tensorflow

I received the following error:

```
FailedPreconditionError: /home/timucin/Thesis/Tagger-master8/train; Is a directory
     [[{{node input_queues/examples_queue/parallel_read/ReaderReadV2}} = ReaderReadV2[_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](input_queues/examples_queue/parallel_read/TFRecordReaderV2, input_queues/examples_queue/parallel_read/filenames)]]
```

While running a training session of semantic role labeling. I`m using python 2.7 (anaconda) with TensorFlow 1.12 on Ubuntu 18.04.

When I first run the script, train directory is created to store checkpoints and the session terminates with no error.

During the second trial, with the train directory already created, the script looks to the checkpoints to asses whether there are new steps on top of already completed ones and terminates with the above mentioned error.

Trace back:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Total trainable variables size: 8187305
INFO:tensorflow:Create CheckpointSaverHook.
INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized.
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from train/model.ckpt-10
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError'>, /home/timucin/Thesis/Tagger-master8/train; Is a directory
         [[{{node input_queues/examples_queue/parallel_read/ReaderReadV2}} = ReaderReadV2[_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](input_queues/examples_queue/parallel_read/TFRecordReaderV2, input_queues/examples_queue/parallel_read/filenames)]]
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 10 into train/model.ckpt.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-6-5b359d738d7d>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/home/timucin/Thesis/Tagger-master8/main.py', args='train --model_name deepatt --vocab_path /home/timucin/Thesis/Tagger-master-old/word_dict /home/timucin/Thesis/Tagger-master-old/label_dict --data_path /home/timucin/Thesis/Tagger-master8/ --model_dir train --model_params=feature_size=100,hidden_size=200,filter_size=800,residual_dropout=0.2,num_hidden_layers=10,attention_dropout=0.1,relu_dropout=0.1 --training_params=batch_size=4096,eval_batch_size=1024,optimizer=Adadelta,initializer=orthogonal,use_global_initializer=false,initializer_gain=1.0,train_steps=15,learning_rate_decay=piecewise_constant,learning_rate_values=[1.0,0.5,0.25],learning_rate_boundaries=[400000,500000],device_list=[0],clip_grad_norm=1.0', wdir='/home/timucin/Thesis/Tagger-master8')

  File "/home/timucin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 704, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/home/timucin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 100, in execfile
    builtins.execfile(filename, *where)

  File "/home/timucin/Thesis/Tagger-master8/main.py", line 892, in <module>
    train(parsed_args)

  File "/home/timucin/Thesis/Tagger-master8/main.py", line 540, in train
    experiment.train()

  File "/home/timucin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/experiment.py", line 389, in train
    saving_listeners=self._saving_listeners)

  File "/home/timucin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/experiment.py", line 886, in _call_train
    input_fn=input_fn, steps=steps, max_steps=max_steps, monitors=hooks)

  File "/home/timucin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 488, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/timucin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 525, in fit
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn=input_fn, hooks=hooks)

  File "/home/timucin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 1095, in _train_model
    _, loss = mon_sess.run([model_fn_ops.train_op, model_fn_ops.loss])

  File "/home/timucin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 783, in __exit__
    self._close_internal(exception_type)

  File "/home/timucin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 821, in _close_internal
    self._sess.close()

  File "/home/timucin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1069, in close
    self._sess.close()

  File "/home/timucin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1229, in close
    ignore_live_threads=True)

  File "/home/timucin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py", line 389, in join
    six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise)

  File "/home/timucin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/queue_runner_impl.py", line 257, in _run
    enqueue_callable()

  File "/home/timucin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1257, in _single_operation_run
    self._call_tf_sessionrun(None, {}, [], target_list, None)

  File "/home/timucin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1407, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)

FailedPreconditionError: /home/timucin/Thesis/Tagger-master8/train; Is a directory
     [[{{node input_queues/examples_queue/parallel_read/ReaderReadV2}} = ReaderReadV2[_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](input_queues/examples_queue/parallel_read/TFRecordReaderV2, input_queues/examples_queue/parallel_read/filenames)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved. Was due to the improper organization of the directory structure...